# Calculating height of a binary tree

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, binary-tree

I tried to implement a method to calculate height of a binary tree by creating a method internal to the binary tree class. It is showing the error None Type object doesn't have attribute height.
here is the code:

```
def height(self):
    if self==None:
        return 0
    else :

            lheight=self.leftChild.height() 

            rheight=self.rightChild.height() 

            if lheight>rheight:
                return lheight+1
            else:
                return rheight+1
```

Comment: @idos actually checked that also, but then it is showing that the rheight is referenced before assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you dont check if right or left are `None`...
For every node before you set lheight and rheight check first that they are not `None`

```
if self.right is not None:
    rheight = self.right.height()
```

They don't check it theirselves because they just don't call `height()` - `None Type` has no `height()` function, the error stands there

Comment: i did this but now it is showing the error- variable lheight referenced before assignment.

Comment: Create it before condition and assign 0 to it (if there is no right, its "height" is 0)

Comment: thanks..but I have one question..in the successive function calls how are the values of lheight and rhight being retained. Shouldn't they be initialized to 0 when the function gets called ?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your question... Explain it to me plz

Comment: yeah...actually what I am asking is that I have initialized both of them to 0 and It is working but since for each left and right child  the function is being called the variables lheight and rheight will be again and agin initialized to 0 right ?

Comment: OK. If I understood right your'e asking about different calls of the function - the function is called a lot of times in one height calculation - why lheight and rheight don't override themselves?  
Is that the question?

Comment: OK very good question:)  
For every new call of a function the interpreter leaves the caller aside for a moment, preforms the called function and then returns to the caller, and continues its code.  
This caller list ( a function in a function in a function) is called the `stack`.  
Anyway, when a function calls itself, the interpreter treats the caller and called as completely separate functions, stored in separate memory and everything. The lheight of one call is not the same variable as the lheight of the other.